# CloudWatch agent - How to troubleshoot apps on EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

Below is the CloudFormation template for EC2 instance, from [here](https://github.com/shamhub/docker-jenkins/blob/master/stack.json#L19):

```
"EC2Instance":{
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties":{
                "ImageId": "ami-05958d7635caa4d04",
                "InstanceType": "t2.micro",
                "SubnetId": { "Ref": "SubnetId"},
                "KeyName": { "Ref": "KeyName"},
                "SecurityGroupIds": [ { "Ref": "EC2InstanceSecurityGroup"} ],
                "IamInstanceProfile": { "Ref" : "EC2InstanceProfile"},
                "UserData":{
                    "Fn::Base64": { "Fn::Join": ["", [
                        "#!/bin/bash\n",
                        "echo ECS_CLUSTER=", { "Ref": "EcsCluster" }, " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config\n",
                        "groupadd -g 1000 jenkins\n",
                        "useradd -u 1000 -g jenkins jenkins\n",
                        "mkdir -p /ecs/jenkins_home\n",
                        "chown -R jenkins:jenkins /ecs/jenkins_home\n"
                    ] ] }
                },
                "Tags": [ { "Key": "Name", "Value": { "Fn::Join": ["", [ { "Ref": "AWS::StackName"}, "-instance" ] ]} }]
            }
        },
```

---

To troubleshoot Jenkins running in EC2, we would like to use cloudwatch agent.

But, [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent-New-Instances-CloudFormation.html) gives pointers on using cloudwatch agent on created stack.

How to create install CloudWatch agent resource type, within existing template(above)?

Comment: there are no resource type called cloudwatch agent , you need to install cloudwatch agent and setup using the cloudformation init scripts.

Comment: @ArunK can you refer to cloudformation init example?

Comment: That's what my comment based on . The agent needs to be installed and configured to collect logs and metrics through cloudformation init scripts